# iTunes Connect still asks Export Compliance for app distributed in U.S. only

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

The App is only distributed in U.S. and I only selected U.S. as available territory, However, after I finished answering Export Compliance questions, iTunes Connect was still asking me to submit ERN documentation - it doesn't make sense as this App will be in U.S. only.

[Here is a screenshot of my answers in Export Compliance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPn3L.png)

Any ideas of how to avoid submitting ERN documentation for App only distributed in U.S.?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Export Compliance FAQ, Apple states:

> **Does my app require a trade compliance review if I only distribute it on the App Store in the U.S. and Canada?**
>   You do not need to go through either the U.S. CCATS or ERN process. However, you will need to answer the encryption questions as they apply to your app, ensure that only Canada and the U.S. are selected on your metadata page and submit a signed and dated letter on your letterhead, reference the app name and ID, certifying that you will only offer your app in the U.S. and/or Canada and that should you decide to expand to other countries at a later date, you will obtain the required U.S. and France approvals as necessary and submit them to Apple’s Export Compliance Department at that time.

Given this, make sure you have already setup the Pricing info to indicate only US distribution.

Then prepare the required letter and submit it when filling out the Export Compliance info for your app.